# С++ как передать строку в шаблон?

Tags: c++, строки, шаблоны-с++

Число работает:

```
template <int age>
class Parent {

};


class Child : public Parent<33> {

};
```

Но как передать строку?

```
template <char *text>
class Parent {

};


class Child : public Parent<"ololo"> {

};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нельзя использовать литеральную строку в шаблонах, так как не понятно, является ли она каждый раз разная, или той же самой. ПО этому придется создать переменную и использовать уже её:

```
template <const char *text>
class Parent {

};

char text[] = "Ololo";
class Child : public Parent<text> {

};
```

Comment: Дело тут отнюдь не в какой-то "динамически генерируемой строке" (да почему это она "динамически генерируемая"), а в том, что стандарт С++ просто явным обращом запрещает использование строковых литералов в качестве параметров шаблонов.

Comment: @AnT почему он это запрещает?

Comment: В стандарте С++98 назвалась конкретная причина - строковый литерал обладает внутренним связыванием (internal linkage), а указатель на объект с внутренним связыванием не может быть аргументом шаблона. (Разрешались только указатели на объекты с внешним связыванием.) В С++11 это ограничение было снято в общем, но тем не менее строковые литералы все равно оставили за бортом. Причина этого скорее всего в том, что строковый литерал в С++ не обладает гарантированной уникальностью.

Comment: Два разных литерала `"HELLO"` в программе могут быть представлены физически одним литералом, а могут так и остаться разными литералами. Таким образом два шаблонных класса `Parent<"HELLO">` могут оказаться разными типами, а могут - одним и тем же типом. Такая неопределенность - нежелательна, и даже вредна.

Comment: Если бы работало ваше решение, то нужно было бы объявлять `template<char text[5]>`. Но оно не работает. Вы бы попробовали сначала...

Comment: @Harry: Это почему это "не работает"? Работает прекрасно. Адрес глобального массива - адресная константа. Все в порядке. См. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/74391efde973e887

Comment: @AnT выходит я все верно сказал, и дал правильный ответ. Ты сам мои слова же и повторил  =). а "динамически генерируется" значит программистом динамически каждый раз набираются буквы. и шаблонизатору не понятно это новый шаблон или все еще тот же.

Comment: @AnT Ну, значит, я не так понимал ситуацию. Или это не проходило в более старой версии C++, а я не проверил на новой.

Answer (score 3):

Я вам сейчас один фокус покажу, только вы о нем никому не рассказывайте :)  Потому как фокус построен чисто на, гм... особенностях Visual C++.

В нем для строки (даже глобальной) просто ее передача - не сработает:

```
template<const char* const text>
    class Test
{
public:
    void out() { cout << text << endl; }
};

const char * const text = "abcd";

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    Test<text> t;
    t.out();
}
```

Но если провернуть вот так, как показано ниже - то Visual C++ 2015 проглотит, не поморщившись:

```
template<char* text>
    class Test
{
public:
    void out() { cout << text << endl; }
};

char * text = "abcd";
char& i = text[0];

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    Test<&i> t;
    t.out();
}
```

Comment: @AnT Ну допишите вы эти const - ничего не изменится... А второй вариант проскочит без всяких const.